# Print SQL statement into log with multiple datasources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring project configured with 2 datasources. I use yml file to configure the project:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: local 
    data:
        rest:
            basePath: /engine
    jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
    jmx:
        enabled: false
    mail:
        default-encoding: UTF-8
        host: someHost.com
        password: somePassword
        port: 587
        properties:
            mail:
                smtp:
                    auth: true
                    connectiontimeout: 5000
                    starttls:
                        enable: true
                    timeout: 5000
                    writetimeout: 5000
        protocol: smtp
        test-connection: true
        username: peter.penzov@gmail.com
    production:
        datasource:
            driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
            jdbc-url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/engine_production
            jpa:
                hibernate:
                    ddl-auto: update
                properties:
                    hibernate:
                        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
                show-sql: true
            password: qwerty
            username: root    
    warehouse:
        datasource:
            driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
            jdbc-url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/engine_warehouse
            jpa:
                hibernate:
                    ddl-auto: update
                properties:
                    hibernate:
                        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
                show-sql: true
            password: qwerty
            username: root
```

Full yml file: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml#L32)

I use this configuration for the [entityManager](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/context/ContextProductionDatasource.java).
I would like to print the SQL statements for every datasource. But for some reason the SQL queries are not printed. Do you know how to configure this is this setup?

Comment: For god's sake remove SMTP credentials and change them (if they are real) as they are already leaked.

Comment: This is a test project, not a production project.

Comment: But anyone could use your personal account which I guess you wouldn't like -)

Comment: Regarding the question - can you show your JpaReposiotiries package structure and datasource config?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/tree/master/src/main/java/org/engine and datasource config: https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/tree/master/src/main/java/org/engine/context

Comment: I believe `jpa.show-sql` is not related to datasource configuration anyhow. It's spring data jpa abstraction layer configuration. Did you try to put `sping.jpa.show-sql: true` property without specifying the datasource?

Comment: No I haven't but the idea is to have `show-sql` independently for very datasource if it's possible.